# Samsung galaxy S GT-I9000 how to

Tags: galaxy, smartphone

I have just bought a second hand Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000. I have some data from the previous owner, like text message history, contact list and so on. I was wondering if there is any way to return its firmware to brand new status. This is my first smartphone, so be gentle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings -> Privacy -> Restore & Backup -> Factory Reset (Wipe data)